# Wifi tethering using PC not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, internet-security

I have a WiFi adapter(TP Link TL-WN721 N), I have enabled the SoftAP mode and connect my tablet to it. I am giving the details of the connection which I got from the tab(runs on Android Jellybean):
Status: Connected

Signal Strength:Excellent

Security:WPA2 PSK

IPv4 address:192.168.137.2

IPv6 address:fe80::20a:ff:fe2a:329

Proxy settings: None

IPv4 settings: static

Gateway: 192.168.137.1

Network prefix length: 24

DNS 1: 192.168.137.1

DNS 2: _

I can use superbeam and Unified remote without any problem.
My Public IP address is 117.250.243.234
My pc's IP address in the WiFi network is 192.168.137.1
My pc is running on Windows 7 Ultimate 64Bit.
UPDATE:
While my antivirus is disable(Avast Internet security), I could get internet access in my tab. But, I don't think that disabling AV is not a good solution, what would you suggest?

Comment: What OS is on the computer actually connected to the Internet?

Comment: "Gateway: **192.168.137.1**" and "pc's IP address in the WiFi network is **192.168.137.1**" this doesn't make sense. Your PC should be getting an IP address via DHCP from the router (gateway). If it has the same IP address as the gateway internet will not work ...

Comment: @BigChris Computer is running on Win7 Ultimate 64bit.

Comment: @DavidPostill I do not have a router, but a USB adapter(TP LINK TL-WN721N).

Comment: @DavidPostill the OP is trying to share the PC's internet connection with the tablet by using the PC's adapter to create a hotspot, so in this case the PC is the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Caution AVAST users who have been facing this issue, just update the program version to 2015, open the window to customize Firewall, there's an option for Internet Connection Sharing under "Preferences", check that box. I have attached a screenshot of the window.[image: Here]